# Connection to "process /usr/sbin/sendmail -bs -i" has been closed unexpectedly

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

Estoy mandando un email con laravel pero al enviarlo me da el siguyiente problema
" Connection to "process /usr/sbin/sendmail -bs -i" has been closed unexpectedly."
mi .ENV tiene lo siguiente

```
MAIL_MAILER=sendmail
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mboxhosting.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME="*****"
MAIL_PASSWORD=********
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS="devs@learnbox.work"
MAIL_FROM_NAME="******"
```

Answer (score 0):

Funcionó para mí.
Agregue la constante `MAIL_SENDMAIL_PATH=` al archivo .env e indique la ruta a mi instalación de sendmail que en mi caso es `'C:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe -t -i'`

```
    MAIL_MAILER=sendmail
    MAIL_SENDMAIL_PATH='C:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe -t -i' // aqui o caminho da instalação do sendmail
    MAIL_HOST=http://localhost 
    MAIL_PORT=2525
    MAIL_USERNAME="*****"
    MAIL_PASSWORD=********
    MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
    MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS="devs@learnbox.work"
    MAIL_FROM_NAME="******"
```

Comment: Hola Marcio, bienvenido y gracias por tu colaboración, las respuestas que son solo código, son consideradas de baja calidad, te sugiero que edites la tuya, y expliques de que forma resuelve el problema planteado, así evitarás que sea cerrada y/o recibir votos negativos. 

ver [como responder](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) para evitar votos negativos y/o que tu repuesta sea eliminada, aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener una medalla!.